# For a dataframe, group by a variable, sort and then eliminate the non-consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

| category | value | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| car | bmw | 1 |
| car | ford | 9 |
| car | mercedes | 2 |
| car | porsche | 3 |
| car | GM | 16 |
| car | tesla | 19 |
| cycle | 3T | 3 |
| cycle | Bianchi | 19 |
| cycle | Alchemy | 4 |
| cycle | Ancheer | 5 |
| cycle | Cannondale | 16 |
| cycle | Colnago | 22 |

I am looking to:

- Group by `category`
- Sort each group by `id`
- Eliminate the rows in the dataframe with non-consecutive `id`'s

So, the expected output would be:

| category | value | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| car | bmw | 1 |
| car | mercedes | 2 |
| car | porsche | 3 |
| cycle | 3T | 3 |
| cycle | Alchemy | 4 |
| cycle | Ancheer | 5 |

Comment: Let us know whether you need further clarification from the solutions below.  If no, kindly please pick a solution that best fit your needs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this which sorts the values based on category and id then calculates diff across each category and retains only consecutive values:

```
c = df.sort_values(['category','id']).groupby("category")['id'].diff().fillna(1).eq(1)
out = df[c.reindex(df.index)]
```

---

```
print(out)

  category     value  id
0      car       bmw   1
2      car  mercedes   2
3      car   porsche   3
6    cycle        3T   3
8    cycle   Alchemy   4
9    cycle   Ancheer   5
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Thanks, yes one can replace `reindex` with `loc` :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not look the smartest solution but it gives correct results in both the current set of sample data and some slightly modified data:

```
import numpy as np

df2 = df.sort_values(['category', 'id'])

mask = (df2.groupby("category")['id'].diff().eq(1)
                                     .replace(False, np.nan)
                                     .bfill(limit=1)
                                     .fillna(False)) 
df2.loc[mask]
```

Here, after sorting, we build a boolean mask for selection of rows with consecutive numbers.  The logic is that whenever we found a row which has a difference with previous row by `.diff()` and this difference is equal to 1, the previous row should also be selected (since they are both consecutive but this consecutive condition is only detected at the 2nd row).  The consecutive status will only be valid within same `category` group.

**Result:**

```
  category     value  id
0      car       bmw   1
2      car  mercedes   2
3      car   porsche   3
6    cycle        3T   3
8    cycle   Alchemy   4
9    cycle   Ancheer   5
```

#### Applying solution to slightly changed data:

Now, let's modify the original sample data, as follows:

- For `Category` = `car` change `id` = `1` to `0`
- For `Category` = `cycle` change `id` = `3` to `2`

**Modified base `df`** :

```
   category       value  id
0       car         bmw   0
1       car        ford   9
2       car    mercedes   2
3       car     porsche   3
4       car          GM  16
5       car       tesla  19
6     cycle          3T   2
7     cycle     Bianchi  19
8     cycle     Alchemy   4
9     cycle     Ancheer   5
10    cycle  Cannondale  16
11    cycle     Colnago  22
```

**Result after applying the solution here:**

```
  category     value  id
2      car  mercedes   2
3      car   porsche   3
8    cycle   Alchemy   4
9    cycle   Ancheer   5
```

Here, we can still get 2 sets of consecutive rows for the 2 groups.

You can compare the results for the different solutions.